# How to get the text inside span data-bind part of html using selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is the `html` snippet I am trying to web scrape using Python Selenium.

I am trying to get the text `Add to bag` which is inside a `span data-bind`.

```
<div class="is-add-item-saving" data-bind="visible: isBusy" style="display: none;"></div>
<span class="aria-live" aria-role="status" aria-live="polite" data-bind="{ text: ariaLiveText }"></span>
<button data-bind="click: addToBag, css : buttonCss, attr: { 'aria-label': resources.pdp_cta_add_to_bag, disabled: isBusy }, markAndMeasure: 'pdp:add_to_bag_interactive'" data-test-id="add-button" aria-label="Add to bag">
    <span class="product-tick" data-bind="visible: showProductTick" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: buttonText">Add to bag</span>

</button>
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
instock_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@data-bind,'text: buttonText')]")
instock_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add to bag')]")
```

When I iterate over these `instock_elements`,

```
for value in instock_element:
     print("text : ",value.text)
     print(" id : ",value.id)
     if len(value.text) == 0:
          text = value.id
     else:
          print(value.text)
          text = value.text
          ins_list.append(text)
```

These are giving me random values like `6489355d-9dd3-4d77-a0d7-b134ce48fae7` but not the text `Add to bag`.

Comment: What is your actual problem? This should succeed as you're using the right xpath to get that span (and it's text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the *text* `Add to bag` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-test-id='add-button'][aria-label='Add to bag'] span").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-test-id='add-button' and @aria-label='Add to bag']//span").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-test-id='add-button'][aria-label='Add to bag'] span"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-test-id='add-button' and @aria-label='Add to bag']//span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in particular the `xpath`):

```
from lxml import html

sample = """<div class="is-add-item-saving" data-bind="visible: isBusy" style="display: none;"></div>
<span class="aria-live" aria-role="status" aria-live="polite" data-bind="{ text: ariaLiveText }"></span>
<button data-bind="click: addToBag, css : buttonCss, attr: { 'aria-label': resources.pdp_cta_add_to_bag, disabled: isBusy }, markAndMeasure: 'pdp:add_to_bag_interactive'" data-test-id="add-button" aria-label="Add to bag">
    <span class="product-tick" data-bind="visible: showProductTick" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: buttonText">Add to bag</span>

</button>"""

print(html.fromstring(sample).xpath("//*[@data-bind='text: buttonText']/text()"))
```

Output:

```
['Add to bag']
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

> id
>
> Internal ID used by selenium.
>
> This is mainly for internal use. Simple use cases such as checking if
> 2 webelements refer to the same element, can be done using ==:
>
> if element1 == element2:
> print("These 2 are equal")

use `value.get_attribute("id")` instead to get id

to get text use:

value.text

if it fails use:

```
value.get_attribute("textContent")
```

as value.text retrieves only text that is displayed in UI

Answer (score 0):

If you are having hard time finding the right element,
Easy way is to instead of finding all the elements of associated with xpath,
You must use the **full xpath** of the individual tag and then get the text of it using **.text**

Example:
`text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("full xpath of the element").text`

Answer (score -1):

You may also use `BeautifulSoup` for this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="is-add-item-saving" data-bind="visible: isBusy" style="display: none;"></div>
<span class="aria-live" aria-role="status" aria-live="polite" data-bind="{ text: ariaLiveText }"></span>
<button data-bind="click: addToBag, css : buttonCss, attr: { 'aria-label': resources.pdp_cta_add_to_bag, disabled: isBusy }, markAndMeasure: 'pdp:add_to_bag_interactive'" data-test-id="add-button" aria-label="Add to bag">
    <span class="product-tick" data-bind="visible: showProductTick" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: buttonText">Add to bag</span>
</button>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tag = soup.find('span',{'data-bind':'text: buttonText'})
print(tag.text)
```

**Output**

```
Add to bag
```

Comment: No need to mix beautifulSoup and built in selenium functions imo.

Comment: Those are two different tools imo

Comment: They are two different tools. But they share a general purpose: parsing a DOM. Selenium already does that with findElements & BS with find. I see BS more for when you're using requests module and need a tool to parse from text.

Comment: Selenium is not specifically a DOM parser, which BS is. The combined use of those two tools is absolutely relevant to me.

Comment: I disagree. I would love to see an example where the use of the two tools makes sense.