# Chrome stores cookies too late local in profile path

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cookies

Since it's not possible via `webdriver.get_cookies()` to get all cookies (same domain and 3rd party cookies), I decided to read the `Cookies` file - which is stored in user profile path as SQLite.

But strangely I just saw that cookies are not being saved to this file in real time. I'm also not sure when the cookies are being stored. I have to wait about 10 seconds then the I can find all cookies there.
Is there any idea how to read all cookies in real time for selenium web driver?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally before collecting and printing the cookies you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611588/how-to-get-the-text-inside-span-data-bind-part-of-html-using-selenium-python/65614404#65614404) for a **visible** element and then collect the [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) as follows:

```
webdriver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))
print(webdriver.get_cookies())
```

Or induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) for an **interactive** element and then collect the [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) as follows:

```
webdriver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))
print(webdriver.get_cookies())
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```