# Selenium wait for javascript timingout

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

What I want to do is to scrape the following site https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:office and specifically the table containing all the tags so everything contained within:

```
<table class="wikitable taginfo-taglist">...<\table>
```

since everything within:

```
<div class="taglist" ...> ... <\div>
```

(the parent of the table) is generated by JavaScript I thought this code could work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, capabilities=caps, executable_path='../statics/geckodriver')
    
    
def get_tag_soup(url):
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "wikitable taginfo-taglist")))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml') 
    except Exception as e:
        soup = e
    
    return soup 

get_tag_soup('https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:office')
```

But when I run this code I just get an `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException('', None, None)` more frustratingly some times if I `WebDriverWait` for the parent of `"wikitable taginfo-taglist"` with  `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "taglist"))` it works.

Comment: if waiting for the parent works, why not do that, then something like table = the_parent.find_element_by_classname('wikitable taginfo-taglist')

Comment: or just wait longer...site may be slow?

Comment: waiting for the parent only works sometimes. Is there a way to wait for the whole site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the table containing all the tags instead of [presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [visibility_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611588/how-to-get-the-text-inside-span-data-bind-part-of-html-using-selenium-python/65614404#65614404) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:office")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.wikitable.taginfo-taglist"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:office")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='wikitable taginfo-taglist']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Key Value Element Description Map rendering Image Count
  office accountant An office for an accountant.
  6 895
  1 967
  14
  office advertising_agency A service-based business dedicated to creating, planning, and handling advertising.
  3 916
  580
  3
  office architect An office for an architect or group of architects.
  5 715
  1 239
  12
  office association An office of a non-profit organisation, society, e.g. student, sport, consumer, automobile, bike association, etc.
  13 054
  3 286
  50
  office charity An office of a charitable organization
  696
  384
  7
  office company An office of a private company
  129 801
  36 951
  608
  office consulting An office for a consulting firm, providing expert professional advice to other companies or organisations.
  1 341
  162
  4
  office coworking An office where people can go to work (might require a fee); not limited to a single employer
  1 297
  320
  7
  office diplomatic
  6 634
  4 065
  95
  office educational_institution An office for an educational institution.
  14 172
  8 563
  175
  office employment_agency An office for an employment service.
  7 300
  1 771
  43
  office energy_supplier An office for a energy supplier.
  2 237
  1 112
  19
  office engineer An office for an engineer or group of engineers.
  454
  98
  2
  office estate_agent A place where you can rent or buy a house.
  44 813
  8 042
  39
  office financial An office of a company in the financial sector
  4 891
  1 588
  24
  office forestry A forestry office
  523
  741
  9
  office foundation An office of a foundation
  1 757
  542
  10
  office government An office of a (supra)national, regional or local government agency or department
  98 289
  70 569
  2 300
  office guide An office for tour guides, mountain guides, dive guides, etc.
  587
  168
  1
  office insurance An office at which you can take out insurance policies.
  34 693
  6 475
  91
  office it An office for an IT specialist.
  9 486
  2 039
  51
  office lawyer An office for a lawyer.
  22 881
  4 841
  22
  office logistics An office for a forwarder / hauler.
  2 796
  677
  8
  office moving_company An office which offers a relocation service.
  605
  252
  4
  office newspaper An office of a newspaper
  3 511
  1 450
  27
  office ngo An office for a non-profit, non-governmental organisation (NGO).
  12 693
  3 565
  58
  office notary An office for a notary public (common law)
  3 860
  548
  9
  office political_party An office of a political party
  3 354
  1 017
  8
  office property_management Office of a company, which manages a real estate property.
  796
  162
  2
  office quango An office of a quasi-autonomous non-governmental organisation.
  366
  233
  4
  office religion office of a community of faith
  5 807
  2 172
  43
  office research An office for research and development
  3 667
  4 545
  348
  office surveyor An office of a person doing surveys, this can be risk and damage evaluations of properties and equipment, opinion surveys or statistics.
  451
  109
  1
  office tax_advisor An office for a financial expert specially trained in tax law
  5 053
  823
  4
  office telecommunication An office for a telecommunication company
  16 968
  4 335
  77
  office visa An office of an organisation or business which offers visa assistance
  95
  1
  0
  office water_utility The office for a water utility company or water board.
  743
  908
  20
  office yes Generic tag for unspecified office type.
  27 434
  36 155
  420
  ```

**Note**: Do ensure you have maximized the browser [Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126078/how-does-selenium-click-on-elements-that-are-50-on-screen-and-50-not-on-screen/59130869#59130869) as follows:

```
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

Comment: Thx for the awnser but both xpath and css selector for me produce the same timeout error. maybe the issues is that the driver isn't rendering the javascript?

Comment: @Thagor Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: sadly it does not solve the issue I tried waiting for 120 seconds which doesn't help either and it tried setting an window size which does nothing as well.

Comment: @Thagor Can you just copy and paste my code and retest please?

Comment: I played a bit more with the code and found that when I do `time.sleep(10)` the table gets rendered but (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "wikitable taginfo-taglist") only works for `"taglist"` not for ` "table.wikitable.taginfo-taglist"` here the code times out

Comment: okay tried it @DebanjanB and the CSS_selector works! `"wikitable taginfo-taglist"` wasn't the right selector